# How to change the way theorems are numbered

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to write a small note in which there are no sections, and the theorems go from 1,2,3. In the following code, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\title{Some Notes}
\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{definition}
 A group is defined as ...
\end{definition}
 \begin{remark}
 The concept of groups...
 \end{remark}
\end{document}
```

I get Definition 0.1. However I want only Definition 1 to be printed instead. Furthermore I want Remark 1, instead of Remark 0.2.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just remove `[section]` and do `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

you're telling LaTeX that `theorem` environments should be numbered as

> `<section number>`.`<theorem number>`

and that the theorem number must be reset when a new section comes along.

The `[section]` part is optional, as the syntax suggests, so you just have to do

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\title{Some Notes}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{definition}
A group is defined as ...
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}
The concept of groups...
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}
Groups are fun.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I now challenge you to prove theorem 3.

Comment: @LeandroAbib Children are fond of playing with monsters.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no section used, the section counter is `0`, therefore the theorem enviroment prints `0.1` etc.

Since the OP has the `remark` as a sibling of theorem environment, it will just increment the theorem counter and the number of the 1st remark will be `0.2`, not `1`.

If `\thetheorem` and `\theremark` commands are redefined such that the section counter value information is removed, the output will be as desired.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[theorem]

\renewcommand{\theremark}{\arabic{theorem}}

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}

\title{Some Notes}
\begin{document}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{definition}\label{def::1}
 A group is defined as ...
\end{definition}
 \begin{remark} \label{remark::1}
 The concept of groups...
 \end{remark}

\begin{definition}
Well....
see \ref{remark::1} as well
\end{definition}
 \begin{remark}
   In \ref{def::1} you saw%
 \end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because we can use it with multiple chapters/sections with the counter still resetting so it's closer to the current behavior